# If $A \times B$ is the direct product of two rings, must $A$ necessarily be a projective $A \times B$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, projective-module

> If $A \times B$ is the direct product of two rings, must $A$ necessarily be a projective $A \times B$-module?

I understand I am supposed to think of $A$ as an $A \times B$-module by identifying it with the ideal $A \times \{0\} \subset A \times B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think yes, a projective module is a direct summand of a free module, and $A \oplus B \simeq A \times B$ as $A \times B$ modules.  The isomorphism sends $(a, 0) + (0, b) \mapsto (a, b)$.